# Fastest way to "jump back" to a file in TextMate?

Tags: macos, editor, textmate

Often, when I am reading code or debugging, I want the ability to quickly jump around files.  I especially want to "go back" to where I was.  I know about "Command+T", "Command+Shift+T",  and, bookmarks.  But, I cannot figure out a way to jump around files quickly.

UPDATE:  I do not think I my question was clear enough judging by two answers given.  Specifically, I am looking for a way to "jump back" to where I was in a file.  I know how to navigate in TextMate (in general).  I want to know if TextMate has a "jump back" key binding.

Answer (score 9):

It's subtle.

The command-T thing has the files listed in Most Recently Used order.
So, you can go command-T return to get back to your last file real quick.  At first I couldn't find it either.

I don't think there's a go to last edit location as there is in, say, IDEA/RubyMine.

Comment: So simple, yet so difficult. I came here searching for a plugin, but there is no need for it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Courtesy of [MacroMates.com](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_multiple_files.html)
2.3 Moving Between Files (With Grace)

When working with projects there are a few ways to move between the open files.

The most straightforward way is by clicking on the file tab you need. This can also be done from the keyboard by pressing ⌘1-9, which will switch to file tab 1-9.

You can also use ⌥⌘← and ⌥⌘→ to select the file tab to the left or right of the current one.

It is possible to re-arrange the file tabs by using the mouse to drag-sort them (click and hold the mouse button on a tab and then drag it to the new location). This should make it possible to arrange them so that keyboard switching is more natural.

One more key is ⌥⌘↑ which cycles through text files with the same base name as the current file. This is mainly useful when working with languages which have an interface file (header) and implementation file (source).

When you want to move to a file which is not open you can use the Go to File… action in the Navigation menu (bound to ⌘T). This opens a window like the one shown below.

Go To File

This window lists all text files in the project sorted by last use, which means pressing return will open (or go to) the last file you worked on. So using it this way makes for easy switching to the most recently used file.

You can enter a filter string to narrow down the number of files shown. This filter string is matched against the filenames as an abbreviation and the files are sorted according to how well they match the given abbreviation. For example in the picture above the filter string is otv and TextMate determines that OakTextView.h is the best match for that (by placing it at the top).

The file I want is OakTextView.mm which ranks as #2. But since I have already corrected it in the past, TextMate has learned that this is the match that should go together with the otv filter string, i.e. it is adaptive and learns from your usage patterns.

Comment: Thanks.  But, not quite what I was looking for . . .

Answer (score 0):

If you have a project window open, you can leave frequently-accessed files open (in tabs), and then use ⌘+1-9 to jump to open tabs.

Comment: Yes.  I do this often.  But, I am really looking for a "jump back to where I was" key binding.